# Email script correction suggestion required

Tags: php, json, email

Can anyone suggest corrections in these few line of code. I am very much disturbed that it is not working and time elapsing. Please help me with corrections or suggest a new one.

```
<?php
$email_to = 'info@khawabnama.com';
$subject = "Contact US";   
$name =$_POST['flname']; 
$email_from = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n"    .     'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

 $success=@mail($email_to, $subject, $body, $headers);  

 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Email sent!'
  );
  //    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From:      <'.$email_from.'>');
echo json_encode($status);
//header("Location: index.php");

//header('Location: http://www.khawabnama.com/index.php');
//die;
```

Comment: receving empty string like this

Comment: receving empty sting like this     Name: 

Email: 

Subject: Contact US

Message:

Comment: Please make sure that your form submission works properly and  didn't find $email value setting.